# libpcap 32 bit on 64 bit Ubuntu

Tags: apt, 64-bit, 32-bit, libpcap

I'm trying to install [Gulp](http://staff.washington.edu/corey/gulp/).

As the author says it needs 32-bit `libpcap-dev` libs for building the application, but when I try to download 32bit version it says

> NO INSTALL CANDIDATE AVAILABLE

How do I solve this?

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit

Comment: Which release are you on ?

Comment: Ubuntu version?? 14.04.02LTS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`libcap-dev` (both 32 and 64 bits) are available in Ubuntu 14.04's main repo.

```
$ apt-cache policy libcap-dev:i386
libcap-dev:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:2.24-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
     1:2.24-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
```

I think you have not enabled the `multiarch` support leading to that error about non-existent package.

To enable `multiarch` support for `i386` architecture so that you can install 32 bit packages on your 64 bit system :

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Now run :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now you should be able to install `libcap-dev` (32 bit) :

```
sudo apt-get install libcap-dev:i386
```